# How to fix "Illegal char <:> at index 37: com.xride.app-mergeDebugResources-115:/values/values.xml" in Android

Tags: java, android, error-handling

this is attr file

```
  <declare-styleable name="WeekdaysPicker">
    <attr name="enabled" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="highlight_color" format="color" />

    <attr name="text_unselected_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="sunday_first_day" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="show_weekend" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="week_end_darker" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="weekend_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="weekend_text_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="full_size" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="recurrence" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="border_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="border_thickness" format="integer" />
    <attr name="border_highlight_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="border_highlight_thickness" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>

<attr name="text_color" format="color" />
<attr name="button_text_color" format="reference" />
<attr name="button_background_color" format="reference" />
<attr name="button_disabled_background_color" format="reference" />
<attr name="background_color" format="reference" />
<attr name="input_layout_background_color" format="reference" />
<attr name="icon_color" format="reference" />
```

Nothing in the project has <:> in it, and tried Invalidate Caches and Restart didn't work, tried changing the attr values name didn't work too.

Comment: That seem not to be the complete file. A valid XML file should have a root element.

Comment: yes the root is just like this "<resources>"